# How to group mongo sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am newbie to mongo, i am trying to take the group by values in a subdocument, and having the mongo collection structure as like :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("589d4e4b270f8b1635d400b1"),
"myShopId" : 439,
"products" : [ 
    {
        "productId" : "1234",
        "productName" : "sambarpowder 500 gm",
        "productCategory" : "masala",           
        "mrp" : "90",           
        "_id" : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006ea9")
    }, 
    {
        "productId" : "5678",
        "productName" : "moong dhal 200 gms",            
        "productCategory" : "dhal",            
        "mrp" : "38 ",
        "_id" : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006eaa")
    },
      {
        "productId" : "5678",
        "productName" : "moong dhal 200 gms",            
        "productCategory" : "dhal",            
        "mrp" : "38 ",
        "_id" : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006eaa")
    }
],
"isAlive" : 1,
"__v" : 3
}
```

Here, I want to do group by in this.
for eg in mysql:

```
select productCategory from products where shopId = '439' groupby productCategory
```

How can i achieve the group by in mongo sub document

```
My Expected output is like : 

category : [{
   productCategory : masala
   _id : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006ea9")
},
{
    productCategory : dhal
   _id : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006eaa")
}
```

]

Comment: I have tried like this db.shopProductDetails.group({
    "key": {
        "products.productCategory": true
    },
    "initial": {},
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {},
    "cond": {
        "shopId": "439"
    }
});

Comment: but i am getting empty element

Comment: That group command variant is deprecated. Use `$group` aggregation instead. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/. For complete set of pipeline stages. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this will help,

```
  db.test.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      myShopId: 439
    }
  }, {
    $unwind: "$products"
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "productCategory": "$products.productCategory"
      },
      "id": {
        $first: "$products._id"
      }
    }
  }])
```

Output:

{ "_id" : { "productCategory" : "dhal" }, "id" : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006eaa") }

{ "_id" : { "productCategory" : "masala" }, "id" : ObjectId("589d595f6da20b72fe006ea9") }

Comment: how to apply limit and offset in the same scenario?

Comment: This will work : db.test.aggregate([{$match:{myShopId:439}},{$unwind:"$products"},{$limit: 8},{$skip:5},{$group:{_id:{"productCategory":"$products.productCategory"},"id": { $first: "$products._id" }}}])