# Push Data to Mongo Document From Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have data with one schema and I'm trying to push it to a document with a different schema. I'd like to push an object to a Mongo document with an array value.

In an Angular component I have a function that validates a form:

```
 public validate(): void {
    ....
    this._httpService.postFormResults(this.user);
  }
```

In the HttpService:

```
  postFormResults(formData: IUser) {
    return this._http
      .post<IUser>("/my-route", formData)
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
      });
  }
```

This is my interface:

```
export class IUser {
  caption: string;
  email: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  country: string;
}
```

Followed by the Express route:
`app.use('/my-route', require('./route..'));`

The route is:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  const formData = new CaptionData({
    caption: req.body.caption,
    email: req.body.email,
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastName: req.body.lastname,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state
  })
  formData.save();
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Form submission added successfully'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userData = mongoose.Schema({
    caption: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String },
    city: { type: String },
    state: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', userData);
```

Everything above is working.
My question is, how do I push the above data to an entirely different structure?
Where do I reference the document ID?
I want the above data (one object) to be pushed to captions shown below. How do I reference the existing Mongo document ID and push the new data?

```
export class UserDataInterface {
  imageURL: string;
  altText: string;
  totalCaptions: number;
  captions: [{userData}, {userData}, {userData}]
  cached: boolean;
  itemIndex: number;
}
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504454/pushing-data-to-array-in-mongodb-document) from 2018. Would this be a viable solution?

`formData.update( { _id: how to get the ID?},  { $push: {"captions": userData}})`

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277231/how-to-group-mongo-sub-document) is also similar but I'm not entirely clear.

Comment: Your `userData` schema represents a `caption` and you need to put this object reference into an array declared in another schema, correct?

Comment: @lpizzinidev
 Correct. Exactly right.